# Tab or Session Manager for Safari 12?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

Safari 12 improved the security of the browser by killing off the older API. Unfortunately in doing so it killed the very handy Sessions: https://sessions-extension.github.io/Sessions/

I can easily go find the tabs I had open when I upgraded.

My challenge - where do I find a robust tool that remembers all of your tabs even after a crash?

(Yes I know of the preference "reopen open all windows from last session" - past experience says that this doesn't work if the browser crashes).

Comment: I wouldn't go all "off-topic" on this one as it is about Safari. Granted, it's about a Safari Extension but it is still Mac software. Also you might have to wait a while for a developer to dig into re-creating that extension for Safari 12. Have you contacted the dev about it? Who knows, it might not even be practical any more...

Comment: SessionRestore from https://sweetpproductions.com works fine on Safari 12.

Comment: Cool I didn't know SessionRestore existed anymore it doesn't show up when searching the extensions in the app store.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same question and found no answer. So I myself developed a Safari extension named [Tab Space](http://yuanzhoucq.github.io/Tab-Space) which could handle this task for me. Try it if you want.

Comment: I bought the plugin. It is missing one or two key features: auto save tab list every X minutes or every hour. This would save from browser crashes/browser forgetfulness. Bonus have an infinitely long undo close tab list.

Answer (score 1):

Followup to my own question. Based on [Marc Wilson](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/89967/marc-wilson) suggestion I'm trying SessionRestore from SweetProductions: https://sweetpproductions.com/ - thus far it does work.

Comment: SessionRestore doesn't seem to work right for me. It only saves some of the tabs and closes out all existing windows when restoring a session, so I lose the old tabs while the new window that opens doesn't include all the tabs that should have been saved.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs Saver for Safari (https://apps.apple.com/in/app/tabs-saver-for-safari/id1440006971?mt=12) is a good one.

Comment: I'm testing this app now and its the first that seems to have autosave built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can still manually install Sessions, which will probably only work for one more release, Developer tools is bound to pull support for it soon!

https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/install-any-safari-extension-macos-mojave/

(I used the json export at https://sessions-extension.github.io/Sessions/export.html to export the tabs sets & import into Sessions)

Comment: That could work. As you note that will still die in a release.

Answer (score 0):

I have develop [this](https://github.com/morsamatias/UltraTabSaver) open source Tab Manager for Safari, maybe its useful to you. I hope you like it. All the comments are welcome.

https://github.com/morsamatias/UltraTabSaver

Comment: Thanks for finding some duplicate questions.